# Why multicast won't allow += sign when delegate instance is created

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

When creating multicast delegates, we need to create an instance first and then we can use += to add the other instances.  But for events we can use += always. What is the reason for this?

```
namespace anonymous_methods
{
    delegate int Summation(int a, int b);

    class Program
    {
        static event Summation sumEvt;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Summation addition =  PerformAddition;
            addition += secondfunction;

            sumEvt += PerformAddition;
            sumEvt += secondfunction;

            Console.WriteLine("addition is {0}", addition(10, 30));
            Console.WriteLine("addition is {0}", sumEvt(10, 30));
            Console.Read();
        }

        static int PerformAddition(int a, int b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("in the peform addtion");
            return (a + b);
        }

        static int secondfunction(int a, int b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("in the subtraction");
            return (a + b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my not-so-humble opinion this is due to lameness in C#'s implementation of events.  They are useless anyway, because if one of the event handlers throws, it ruins it for all remaining event handlers.  Don't use C# built-in events, roll your own multicasting mechanism.

Comment: Nakis thanks for the response. Wanted to know the reason why difference is there                                                                   
         Summation addition =  PerformAddition; //here we assing 
        addition += secondfunction;  //then we add                                                 
         sumEvt += PerformAddition;
        sumEvt += secondfunction;

Comment: It is actually the *definite assignment rule* that you are asking about.  C# insists that a variable must always be initialized before use.  Events and properties don't have to be initialized.  Mostly because it is perfectly valid to not do so.  They are *accessors*, intended to limit access to their backing field and that field may be initialized.  Note how an event is a lot like a property, the only difference is for an event you don't have to write the add and remove accessors explicitly, the C# compiler auto-generates them.  You could write a property and you'd be happy.

Comment: True but it's important to understand that += on a regular MulticastDelegate whether a field, property, parameter, or local variable is not the same exact operation as += on an event

Answer (score 0):

A class declared with an event (which is like a property except it has an add/remove method, instead of a get/set method) doesn't behave the same way as a Delegate instance. The C# compiler treats it differently and there is also some different handling in the IL.

Jon Skeet wrote a good article on this
http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx